# Debugger was found - this software cannot be executed under the Debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug a program I created in Visual Studio when I receive the error:

> System.TypeInitializationException   HResult=0x80131534   Message=The
> type initializer for '' threw an exception.
> Source=MaterialFileManagerSQLNet   StackTrace:    at
> MaterialFileManagerSQLNet.frmMaterialManager.getAPILookupMaterial() in
> D:\Ctes
> Utilities\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\frmMaterialManager.cs:line
> 397    at
> MaterialFileManagerSQLNet.frmMaterialManager.populateDatagrid(String
> item) in D:\Ctes
> Utilities\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\frmMaterialManager.cs:line
> 347    at MaterialFileManagerSQLNet.frmMaterialManager..ctor() in
> D:\Ctes
> Utilities\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\frmMaterialManager.cs:line
> 39    at MaterialFileManagerSQLNet.Program.Main() in D:\Ctes
> Utilities\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\MaterialFileManagerSQLNet\Program.cs:line
> 17
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> A.SBO.RG()
> .()
>
> Inner Exception 1: Exception: Debugger was found - this software
> cannot be executed under the Debugger.

This is a C# WinForms program. It is adding and updating data to a sql server database hosted in a cloud.
it breaks here:

```
lsLookupMaterial = getAPILookupMaterial();
```

and resolves here:

```
private List<LookupMaterial> getAPILookupMaterial()
    {
        mGlobalSettings.saveSettings();
        List<LookupMaterial> lsLookupMaterial = new List<LookupMaterial>();
        if (mGlobalSettings.Server == E_Server.Local)....
```

I cannot even step into the function without the error occurring.

Has anyone encountered this? This feels like a project setting somewhere but I am unsure. I am already running under admin.

Comment: Looks like you are using some thrid party library inside getAPILookupMaterial(), which has debugger check in it's code and explicitly throws this exception.

Comment: Looks like you have to give somebody a chunk of money to acquire a "developer license".  Can't tell you who to call, they used an obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we have our own obfuscated code I was trying to step through. Got the latest signed code and all was well.